# cordova-plugin-phone-dialer error(PhoneDialer.m:50:133)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am creating an ionic app and have the following tag for calling the phone number displayed on screen:

```
<a href="tel:{{vm.user.contactNumber}}" class="">{{vm.user.contactNumber}}</a></p>
```

However, when I am trying to build the app for ios, the process is breaking with a weird error:

> ```
> Plugins/cordova-plugin-phone-dialer/PhoneDialer.m:21:133: error: unexpected ';' before ')'
>                 if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",
> ```
>
> number]]];) {
>
> ```
> /Plugins/cordova-plugin-phone-dialer/PhoneDialer.m:50:133: error: unexpected ';' before ')'
>                 if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",
> ```
>
> number]]];) {
>
> ```
> /cordova-plugin-phone-dialer/PhoneDialer.m:7:17: warning: method definition for 'call:withDict:' not found
> ```
>
> [-Wincomplete-implementation]
>       @implementation PhoneDialer

Now since the PhoneDialer must be a community plugin already being used by many users, I am assuming there is some error in my code that triggered this error.

Can someone who has used the plugin before please point out the error and the right way to use it in the code? Or confirm if the error is actually in the plugin ??

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know the actual value that `{{vm.user.contactNumber}}` is outputting?

Comment: Its a ten digit contact number: like 1234567654 . But actual value comes into picture a lot later when the app is running. This is happening at the build time which should ideally have nothing to do with the actual value being put at the runtime, no?